# Erase a path in raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael, paint

After looking at the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) of raphael.js, I was only able to find the [Paper.clear()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.clear) and [Element.attr({'clip-rect':...})](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) methods for "erasing" the paper. The former erases the entire paper and the latter clips parts of existing elements.

Is it possible to erase a "path" within the paper, mimicking an actual erase tool?

Or is there a better library better suited for implementing a simple MS Paint/Photoshop clone?

Comment: You can always remove a given element by calling `element.remove` -- but, when you suggest "mimicking an actual erase tool," it sounds as though you're looking for an animation.  Can you provide an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @KevinNielsen, say there are a bunch of shapes and paths on the paper, how would I erase a path? You know...a regular physical pencil eraser.

Comment: If you want pixel-level control then use canvas instead of svg.

Comment: I haven't used a physical pencil for many years, to be honest -- I forgot how they worked ;-)  @ErikDahlström is right -- if you want to simulate the process of erasing a shape, you'd need to use canvas (or apply a clever overlay to your svg, but I doubt that would be worthwhile)

Comment: got it thanks! @ErikDahlström's comment should be the answer.